# Python asyncio.create_subprocess_shell doesn't run multiple subprocesses at the same time

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio

I have a built cpp file which takes in some parameters and executes the code depending on those parameters. What I want to do, is run multiple built files in seperate processes. I decided to look into using asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(). And I noticed some strange behavior. Here is the code:

```
import asyncio


async def run_bash_command(command: str) -> None:
    print(command)
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        command,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    await proc.wait()


async def run():
    tasks = []
    for i in range(10):
        cmd = f'./main {i}'
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(run_bash_command(cmd)))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(run())
```

So, my c++ script takes a lot of time to run.

When I run this code it freezes on the first task and doesn't go to the next one until the first one finishes.
I want them to run parallel. What am I doing wrong?

My operation system is linux, python version is 3.8.10

I don't want to use thread or pure subprocesses. I want to code to be asynchronous, so I can integrate it into my async system.

I tried searching for this, but found nothing. I also tried changing stdout and stderr and it didn't work either.

Comment: "works for me"  -I took your exact code, and just replaced the "./main {i}" command for "sleep 1", and added one extra print when each process is over: it _did_ run 10 "sleep" commands in 1 second, in parallel. (Python 3.11 here)

Comment: everything else being equal, sorry for stating the obvious, but we have to check: are you sure your "main" program is not in-fact consuming close to 100% of your CPU, including all cores? Having the processes run in parallel won't make your machine faster. (although they should at least start  in parallel)

Comment: No, 100% sure it doesn't. I run it on cloud server with over 28 cores

Comment: Sleep command also works for me as expected.